# Python Polars: how to convert a list of dictionaries to polars dataframe without using pandas

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Joe", "lastname": "Bloggs"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Bob", "lastname": "Wilson"}]
```

And I would like to transform it to a polars dataframe. I've tried going via pandas but if possible, I'd like to avoid using pandas.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass it to `pl.DataFrame`

```py
In [2]: pl.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "name": "Joe", "lastname": "Bloggs"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Bob", "lastname": "Wilson"}])
Out[2]:
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ name ┆ lastname │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str      │
╞═════╪══════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ Joe  ┆ Bloggs   │
│ 2   ┆ Bob  ┆ Wilson   │
└─────┴──────┴──────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Polars has a [from_dicts](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.from_dicts.html) method that seems to work sometimes, but I haven't found it 100% reliable yet. Instead Pandas is much more reliable:

```py
pl.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame.from_records(list_of_dicts))
```

I'm currently getting the error `TypeError: PyDataFrame.read_dicts() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given` when trying to use from_dicts() in polars on some data I'm using.
Polars is pretty new so there are still growing pains and weird bugs that are tricky to find/notice.

Comment: Do you have a reproducer for the error? Can you file a bug?

Comment: @jqurious that's going to be impossible because it was on proprietary data, sorry. Also it seemed to work on some similar data and then not on other data. Will try to open a bug if I can in the future.